# html5 video can't play after pause

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I am struggling with the auto pause and then play(manual) again issue.The video is pausing after 2 seconds which is fine. Now there is another button and on click that button the video should start playing from the position it was paused.

Here is my code(html):

```
<div class="restart">Restart after pause</div>
<video id="video" width="400" height="400" id="video" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/sintel/trailer.mp4" controls autoplay />
```

jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $('#video').get(0).play();


    setInterval(function () {
        if ($('#video').get(0).currentTime >= 2) {
            $('#video').get(0).pause();
        }
    }, 100);


    $(".restart").click(function(event){

         $('#video').get(0).play();


    setInterval(function () {
        if ($('#video').get(0).currentTime >= 6) {
            $('#video').get(0).pause();
        }
    }, 100);
    });

});
```

I am definitely not on the right path regarding current time and set time.Please suggest.

The JSFiddle is

http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/KmQxL/10/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you dont clear your interval it will always keep pausing since currentTime will be greater or equal to 2

Comment: also, rather than intervals, use the `timeupdate` event

Comment: Good spot on....It's working now..Thank you so much.Fiddle updated now.

Comment: How can I use timeupdate event with jquery.No idea :(

Comment: Pretty sure it is `$("video")[0].addEventListener('timeupdate', function(event){...});`

Comment: I tried with it but unfortunately it's not working.Sure I am missing something.

Comment: make sure you replace "video" with you actual ID or class so "#video" in your case it looks like

Comment: I did that.It's not stopping.I will try again.

Comment: There is another problem.I have changed the logic a bit and now it doesn't work even using setinterval.http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/KmQxL/11/

Comment: what part doesn't work? You aren't clearing your second interval

Comment: If you check this new one http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/KmQxL/14/ then I am having 2 onclick event.The first start button works but not the second restart link.clear interval is not working for the restart.

Answer (score 2):

Please review this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VZuuF/1/

I got rid of your setIntervals as they are unneccessary with the `timeupdate` event available.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var checkedFirst = false;
    var checkedSecond = false;
    $player = $('#video').get(0);
    $player.play();

    $player.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(event)
    {
        console.log($player.currentTime); 
        if ($player.currentTime >= 2 && !checkedFirst)
        {
            checkedFirst = true;
            $player.pause();
        }

        if ($player.currentTime >= 6 && !checkedSecond)
        {
            checkedSecond = true;
            $player.pause();
        }
    });


    $(".restart").click(function(event)
    {
        $player.play();
    });
});
```

Comment: Brilliant. I have modified a little bit so now I have two controls.Thank you so much for your help. I started today morning and now it's 8pm.Learned a lot.Thanks once again.

Comment: Hey Ronnie thanks once again.I just implemented in my original code and running perfectly.Thank you so much.

Comment: awesome glad it worked out for you. Don't forget to accept the answer